# Parsing XML file with groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have the following XML file. I was able to read it using the xmlParser class.

```
 def records = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
```

I don't know how to extract the row attributes and value.  Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataSet>
    <info>
        <name>test xml</name>        
    </info>
    <columns>        
        <column name="subject" description="subject name" type="xs:string" maxLen="300" nillable="true" />
        <column name="rankid" description="Rank" type="xs:string" maxLen="30" nillable="true" />
    </columns>
    <data>
        <row>
            <column name="subject">English</column>
            <column name="rankid">3</column>        
        </row>
        <row>
            <column name="subject">Computer</column>
            <column name="rankid">4</column>        
        </row>        
    </data>
</dataSet>
```

I want this output:

```
English,3
Coputer,4
```

Can you help me do this in groovy?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the XML after parsing it?

Comment: create the arrayor objct and display info in the webpage using grials gsp page.

Comment: Ok, so you want to read in the XML and turn it into an array of Row objects? Something like this: `[{subject="English",rankid=3},{subject="Computer",rankid=4}]`

Comment: yes, I want to create row eaach row item

Answer (score 2):

Does

```
def data = records.data.row.collect {
  it.column*.text()
}
```

Work?